# Paper.js doesn't draw multiple shapes

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I'm totally new to JavaScript, so I'm asking for help. I'm trying to create a simple Solar system simulation which is represented as several small circles (planets) moving around one big circle (Sun). I use Paper.js to create animations.

I created two classes: Star and Planet. Star class has draw() method which draws the star, and Planet class has motion() method which makes a planet move.

The problem is that when I create several objects and call their draw()/motion() methods, and then try to run script, the last object I created is the only one to be drawn/animated.

For instance, in this code:

```
var sun = new Star("Sun", 400, 400, 50, '#fff250');
sun.draw();


var earth = new Planet("Earth", sun, 100, 10, 1.5, '#b6f7ff');
earth.motion();

var mars = new Planet("Mars", sun, 200, 10, 0.5, '#ff9485');
mars.motion();
```

mars.motion() will work just fine, but two other methods are just ignored. If I remove this method, The Earth will appear and so on.

Here is full code:

```js
function Star(name, xCoordinate, yCoordinate, radius, color) {
    this.name = name;
    this.xCoordinate = xCoordinate;
    this.yCoordinate = yCoordinate;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.color = color;


    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    paper.setup(canvas);

    this.draw = function () {

        var circle = new paper.Path.Circle(new paper.Point(xCoordinate, yCoordinate), radius);
        circle.fillColor = color;
    }

}

function Planet(name, parentStar, distanceFromStar, radius, period, color) {
    this.name = name;
    this.parentStar = parentStar;
    this.distanceFromStar = distanceFromStar;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.period = period;
    this.color = color;

    var xCoordinate = parentStar.xCoordinate + distanceFromStar;
    var yCoordinate = parentStar.yCoordinate + distanceFromStar;

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    paper.setup(canvas);

    this.motion = function () {


        var circle = new paper.Path.Circle(new paper.Point(xCoordinate, yCoordinate), radius);
        circle.fillColor = color;

        paper.view.onFrame = function (event) {

            circle.position.x = parentStar.xCoordinate - distanceFromStar * Math.cos(period * event.time);
            circle.position.y = parentStar.yCoordinate - distanceFromStar * Math.sin(period * event.time);
        }

    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    var sun = new Star("Sun", 400, 400, 50, '#fff250');
    sun.draw();


    var earth = new Planet("Earth", sun, 100, 10, 1.5, '#b6f7ff');
    earth.motion();

    var mars = new Planet("Mars", sun, 200, 10, 0.5, '#ff9485');
    mars.motion();

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="paper-core.js"></script>
    <script src="solar-system.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas1" resize="" style="user-select: none; touch-action: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" width="800" height="800" ></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

I think that the possible reason is that I do this

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
paper.setup(canvas);
```

every time I create a new object, but I'm not sure about it. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption of the problem.

You are setting up the whole canvas each time you draw an element.

You only need to set it up once (*just removed the setup from the draw methods and added it to the `window.onload`*).

Another issue is that you are assigning each planets *update* code as the  `paper.view.onFrame`. But it can only contain a single function. For this i have create a list in which the *update* functions of each planet go and then in the `paper.view.onFrame` i iterate over the array and execute each planets function.

Here is your code with the changes

```js
var planetList = [];

function Star(name, xCoordinate, yCoordinate, radius, color, canvas) {
  this.name = name;
  this.xCoordinate = xCoordinate;
  this.yCoordinate = yCoordinate;
  this.radius = radius;
  this.color = color;

  this.draw = function() {

    var circle = new paper.Path.Circle(new paper.Point(xCoordinate, yCoordinate), radius);
    circle.fillColor = color;
  }

}

function Planet(name, parentStar, distanceFromStar, radius, period, color, canvas) {
  this.name = name;
  this.parentStar = parentStar;
  this.distanceFromStar = distanceFromStar;
  this.radius = radius;
  this.period = period;
  this.color = color;

  var xCoordinate = parentStar.xCoordinate + distanceFromStar;
  var yCoordinate = parentStar.yCoordinate + distanceFromStar;

  this.motion = function() {


    var circle = new paper.Path.Circle(new paper.Point(xCoordinate, yCoordinate), radius);
    circle.fillColor = color;
    planetList.push( function(event) {

      circle.position.x = parentStar.xCoordinate - distanceFromStar * Math.cos(period * event.time);
      circle.position.y = parentStar.yCoordinate - distanceFromStar * Math.sin(period * event.time);
    });
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
  paper.setup(canvas);

  var sun = new Star("Sun", 400, 400, 50, '#fff250', );
  sun.draw();


  var earth = new Planet("Earth", sun, 100, 10, 1.5, '#b6f7ff');
  earth.motion();

  var mars = new Planet("Mars", sun, 200, 10, 0.5, '#ff9485');
  mars.motion();
  
  paper.view.onFrame = function(event){
    var pLen = planetList.length,
        p;
    for (p=0;p<pLen;p++){
      planetList[p](event);
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.10.3/paper-full.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas1" resize="" style="user-select: none; touch-action: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘  it was solving a part of the problem. I have just added the rest of the solution.